# Where is that modified version rails3 running on macruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macruby

http://www.macruby.org/blog/2010/04/30/macruby06.html

In MacRuby blog. They said that:

> This release also passes about 85% of RubySpecs, is able to run a modified version of Rails 3, and implements better support for Ruby 1.9 encodings.

How can I get that modified version rails3? Google cannot give me answer.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't realize the patches we made because the plan is to run vanilla Rails. Patching Rails is required because of bugs in MacRuby not behaving the same as MRI in some edge cases.